# What is the name of this AC plug, and do they still exist?

Tags: identification, plug

Many years ago, I came across a Type I AC power plug, which was effectively a standard plug and double adapter combined. The cable would run to the plug perpendicular to create a lower profile from the wall, and the flat top of the plug would allow you to insert another plug.

I have not seen one of this since, and I'm not sure if that's due to lack of popularity, practicality, safety, or price. However, I'd be very interested to know what its name would be.

Comment: "Tapon" was the common name 'back then'. Common in NZ too.

Comment: And still - [here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ACYBGNRO40QRRREjLW70uCzuHj83EewFhQ:1569674822504&q=nz+tapon+plug&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix6NSxxvPkAhXz7XMBHdGeAbcQsAR6BAgJEAE&biw=3413&bih=1708&dpr=1.13)

Comment: Highly useful was an "insulated phase" or "isolated phase" tapon. The phase pin and the extension phase socket were (are) isolated and each has its own screw terminal. You wire them to a 4 wire cable: earth-neutral- phase in- phase out. Plug a device into the outlet of one and you can on/off control it via the cable. VERY useful.

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by "Type I" you mean the australian plug IIRC they are no longer allowed to be sold as separate plugs to the general public (apparently there were problems with people making up cords with the stackable plugs on both ends), but are apparently still available for professional use and are certainly still available as part of ready-made extension leads.

---

From some further searching it seems the term is "piggy back". Googling "australian piggyback plugs" finds a few results, including a claim from Schnider electric (who bought out clipsal) that they are still available but only to OEM customers with a minimum order of 100 units.

One of the other results from that google search mentions a part number "PDL 940 CL", removing the "CL" (which appears to be a color identifier) from that part number and googling "PDL 940" turns up a couple of suppliers, they seem fairly pricey though.

Comment: I found some at a stage lighting supplier

Comment: Correct, the Australian plug. Yeah, I had a feeling it might have been due to a 'stupid people being stupid people' issue. Any idea what the name of those plugs would be? Assuming there's no other issue with the plugs, I'm interested in grabbing a bunch (moving countries, so it's time to snip some plugs!). I'm sure I can find them somewhere, if I had a name.

Comment: The problem with the double cord is less killing your own children (Darwin Award) than using both male ends to backfeed your house from a generator, tossing line voltage up to the poletop, through the transformer and pummeling some poor lineman with 12,000 volts.